# Track Funnel to Shop Main Page

Tags: google-analytics

Say I have a website where the main page is `mydomain.com/`
Then I have a shop subdomain where the main page of the shop is `shop.mydomain.com/`

I have set up cross domain tracking and that's working fine. I'm a bit confused about how to track the following as a funnel:

`mydomain.com/` -> `shop.mydomain.com/`

Since the funnel setup doesn't consider the domain and the path is both `/`, wouldn't GA see this as the same page?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to see the domain name as well as the Request URI in your reports, create an Advanced filter for your view with the following settings:

```
Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced
Field A: Hostname
Extract A: (.*)
Field B: Request URI
Extract B: (.*)
Output To: Request URI
Constructor: $A1$B1
```

[Source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en)